# Como arrumar este código?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

1. Quando pressiono no teclado, por exemplo o "w" para ir para frente, o robo vai para frente e as vezes outro motor liga junto.
2. Quando pressiono um comando e mantenho pressionado, ao parar de pressionar o motor ainda continua ligado, devido ao time definido(acumula), uma solução é definir um keydown/keyup, como posso fazer isto?

INFORMAÇÕES ADICIONAIS: estou usando uma Raspberry e uma ponte h L298N, para ligar dois motores (estou fazendo testes para um robô).

Espero sugestões de melhorias e desde já agradeço.

Código abaixo:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import sys
import Tkinter as tk

def init():

    gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
    gpio.setup(7, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(11, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(13, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(15, gpio.OUT)

def frente(tf):
    gpio.output(7, False)
    gpio.output(11, True)
    gpio.output(13, True)
    gpio.output(15, True)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def tras(tf):
    gpio.output(7, True)
    gpio.output(11, False)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def esq(tf):
    gpio.output(7, True)
    gpio.output(11, True)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, True)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def dir(tf):
    gpio.output(7, False)
    gpio.output(11, False)
    gpio.output(13, True)
    gpio.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()


def key_input(event):
    init()
    print 'Key:', event.char
    key_press = event.char
    sleep_time = (0.02)

    if key_press.lower() == 'w':
        frente(sleep_time)
    elif key_press.lower() == 's':
        tras(sleep_time)
    elif key_press.lower() == 'a':
        esq(sleep_time)
    elif key_press.lower() == 'd':
        dir(sleep_time)


janela = tk.Tk()
janela.bind('<KeyPress>', key_input)
janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Esse [link](https://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-gpio-modo-input-python/) deve te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, o evento `KeyPress` é chamado sempre que uma tecla é pressionada - e em geral o sistema operacional vai ter um "auto-repeat" automático: ou seja, se o usuário não soltar a tecla, vários eventos de `KeyPress` são enviados - E, inclusive os eventos que acontecerem enquanto o a pausa do `time.sleep` estiver em vigor, serão "encavalados"  -

Ou seja - vamos supor que o tempo de repetição de tecla do sistema seja de "0.1" segundos e sua pausa seja de `1` segundo: chegariam 10 eventos de keypress durante um único time.sleep, ocasionando 10 chamadas seguidas as funções que respondem às direções, mesmo que as teclas tenham sido soltas.

E a situação reversa também pode ser ruim do ponto de vista do usuário: você tem um `time.sleep` de 0.02 segundos, e a reptição do sistema ocorre a cada 0.1 - quer dizer que o motor seria acionado por "soquinhos": fica ligado 0.02 segundos, espera-se 0.08 segundos entre um acionamento e outro.

Bom - o que você precisa é ativar o motor quando receber o primeiro `<KeyPress>` e parar o mesmo quando receber o evneto de `<KeyRelease>` - e,ou não depender de um tempo de `time.sleep`, ou achar uma outra forma de contabilizar o tempo até uma parada automática. (por exemplo, algum mecanismo que tenha que ficar exatamente o tempo X ligado, indepente do tempo que a tecla for pressionada).

Re-escreva as funções de direção desta forma:

```
def frente():
    gpio.output(7, False)
    gpio.output(11, True)
    gpio.output(13, True)
    gpio.output(15, True)
```

e pode manter a função `key_input` quase como está, mas sem passar o parâmetro de sleep - e uma nova função:

```
def keyup(event):
    if event.char in "wasd":
         gpio.cleanup()
```

E, claro, associa-la ao evento de soltar uma tecla:

```
janela.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
```

Agora, se o motor deve realmente ficar ligado apenas por 0.02 segundos, você precisa de algo um pouco mais complexo - em vez de usar o time.sleep, usar a chamada `after` do tkinter - e só "liberar" uma tecla para ser "repetida" depois que a tecla correspondente for pressionada.

Crie um dicionário no módulo, para guardar o estado de cada tecla, "False" para "solta" e "True" para pressionada, e só chame as funções de acionamento se a tecla não estava previamente presisonada.

Mude as funções de acionamento para esse modelo:

```
def esq(tf):
    gpio.output(7, True)
    gpio.output(11, True)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, True)
    # Faz a pausa sem bloquear o fluxo do programa:
    tkinter.after(tf * 1000, gpio.cleanup)

pressed_keys = {
  "w": False, "s": False, "a": False, "d": False
}
# e aproveitando um atalho em vez dos "if" repetitivos:
movement_funcs = {
   "w": frente, "s": tras, "a": esq, "d": dir
}



def key_input(event):
    # O "init" realmente tem que ser chaamdo em cada keypress?
    # se sim,  mova essa chamada para dentro das funções de movimento- 
    # assim, os keypress repetidos não vão resetar os GPIOs.
    # mas me parece que essa chamada deveria ser feita no setup da aplicação
    # apenas uma vez:
    init()
    print 'Key:', event.char
    key_press = event.char
    sleep_time = (0.02)

    if event.char in "wsad" and not pressed_keys[event.char]:
         pressed_keys[event.char] = True
         movement_funcs[event.char](sleep_time)

def keyup(event):
    if event.char in "wsad":
        pressed_keys[event.char] = False

# E claro:
janela.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
```